# Popup window dismiss on outside touch

Tags: android, popup, android-alertdialog

i have googled a lot but not get the answer...

Here is what i am trying to do...

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)screen.getSystemService(screen.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    layout =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.snap_log_viewer,null);

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SnapLog_Activity.this);


                    builder.setView(layout);

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create(); 
 alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                    alertDialog.show();

 WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

                    Window window = alertDialog.getWindow();
                    alertDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
                    lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());

                    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                    window.setAttributes(lp);
```

and want to dismiss when touch outside...

tried

```
setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

but not getting ouptput..

Comment: Add `alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)

Comment: i tried but its  not happening i have also updated my source... @Ken Wolf

Comment: Remove all the stuff after `alertDialog.show()` and try again

Comment: i did but not happening... @Ken Wolf

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be adding flags, and messing around with how the alertDialog is built after you have built it. 
how about try all this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(**CURRENTACTIVITY**.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.titleString));
alertDialog.setMessage(text);
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int arg1) 
{
dlg.dismiss();
}
     });


alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
alertDialog.show();
            return;

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set cancelable to true before showing it.

```
alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
```